# Moq HttpRequest exception error

Tags: .net, vb.net, unit-testing, moq

I have a unit test to mock HttpRequest object, trying to set up mock in this test case (VB code):

```
    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub Test()

        Dim Request = New Mock(Of System.Web.HttpRequestBase)()
        Dim Context = New Mock(Of System.Web.HttpContextBase)()


        Request.Setup(Function(x) x.Params("FieldName")).Returns("test")
        Context.Setup(Function(x) x.Request).Returns(Request.[Object])

       '...
       'Call controller method here.

    End Sub
```

But I got exception error message:
https://www.screencast.com/t/XiZIfO4Xam

Any suggestions about this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moq can only modify overridable members. `HttpRequestBase.Params` is a `NameValueCollection`

You get the error because the `NameValueCollection` property

```
Public Property Item (name As String) As String
```

is not overridable.

Use an actual `NameValueCollection` and pass that as the `Params` property

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub Test()
    `Arrange
    Dim Request = New Mock(Of System.Web.HttpRequestBase)()
    Dim httpContext = New Mock(Of System.Web.HttpContextBase)()

    Dim parameters As New NameValueCollection()
    parameters("FieldName") = "test"

    Request.Setup(Function(x) x.Params).Returns(parameters)
    httpContext.Setup(Function(x) x.Request).Returns(Request.[Object])

    Dim controller = New BookingController(...)
    `assign the mock http context to controller
    controller.ControllerContext = New ControllerContext()
    controller.ControllerContext.Controller = controller
    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = httpContext.[Object]

    `Act
    `...

    `Assert
    `...

End Sub
```

Now you have more flexibility to arrange behavior of the mocked request

Comment: Great it's working this way. Thanks Nikosi. But when I request this field value in the controller method, it couldn't get this value. This is my controller method:

Comment: Public Function SaveRecord()

        Dim FieldNo As Integer

        FieldNo = Request.Params("FieldName")
     ...

   End Function

Comment: Is it the right way to get request("FieldName")? Let me know if I am wrong, it's the first time I use moq object.

Comment: I called the controller method in the Test Method above.

Comment: How are you setting the context to the controller?

Comment: Public Sub Initialize()
            dbUnitTestContext = new BookingContext()
            Controller = New BookingController(dbUnitTestContext)
        End Sub

Comment: Do I need to set mock context, mock controller?

Comment: @Julia this is exactly the reason I asked you to provide the relevant details on your other question. It will drastically reduce the back and forth with trying to figure out what is the actual problem as we will have to constant ask for more details as you try to apply our suggestion piece by piece.

Comment: Excellent it's working perfectly by assigning mock http context to controller. Thanks so much Nkosi :)

Comment: @Julia glad it is working. In future try to make sure your questions are [mcve] so that those helping you can provide you with it. Take some time and also read [ask]

Comment: maybe you can help me mock My.User.IsInRole(), I created another ticket regarding this.